# Install mongodb driver for php 7.1 on RHEL 7.1

Tags: php, php-7, pecl, php-7.1, rhel7

I am trying to install mongodb driver for php 7.1 but not found any solution.

Used following command

```
pecl install mongodb
```

But gives , pecl command not found. Tried to install pecl by

```
yum install pecl
```

But given no package available

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I want install mongodb driver extension for php7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try install `php-pear` package. `pecl` is included on it.

P.S. See https://pkgs.org/download/php-pear

Comment: Can you try to install `php-pecl` or `php-pecl-php` packages? @PrashantGPatil

Comment: What package did you used for install `php`? (I mean did you used `yum install php` or `yum install php7` or what?)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use yum packages:

```
yum install php71-php-pecl-mongodb.x86_64 -y
```